# Plotting error while using ggplot faceting function in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to do the comparison of my observed and modeled data sets for two stations. One station is called station "red" and another is called "blue". I was able to create the facets but when I tried to add two series in one facet, only one facet got updated while other didn't.

This means for blue only one series is plotted and for red two series are plotted.

The code I used is as follows:

```
    # install.packages("RCurl", dependencies = TRUE)
require(RCurl)
out <- postForm("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ainioj2nn47sis4/watersurf1.csv?dl=1", format="csv")
watersurf <-  read.csv(textConnection(out))
watersurf[1:100,]

watersurf$coupleid <- factor(rep(unlist(by(watersurf$id,watersurf$group1,
                                           function(x) {ave(as.numeric(unique(x)),FUN=seq_along)}
                                           )),each=6239))


p <- ggplot(data=watersurf,aes(x=time,y=data,group=id))+geom_line(aes(linetype=group1),size=1)+facet_wrap(~coupleid)
p
```

Is it also possible to add a third series in the graph but of unequal length (i.e not same interval)?

The output is [image]
I followed the example on this page to create the graphs.
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/growth.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for,

```
ggplot(data = watersurf, aes( x = time, y = data))
       + geom_line(aes(linetype = group1, colour = group1), size = 0.2) 
       + facet_wrap(~ id)
```

Comment: Hello Eric, Thank you for your reply. I don't think here the issue is with scale. The series of both stations have more or less same range so the scale shouldn't be a problem. Would you please see the graph ? I think it has something to do with legend. But I couldn't figure it out.Thanks.

Comment: @Jdbaba,I obviously misunderstood your question. You have two plots in your example 1) `ggplot(data=watersurf,aes(x=time,y=data))+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~id)` 2), and the ones that ends with, `p`. I'm not sure what you want then. Whene I look at `table(watersurf$group1, watersurf$coupleid)` it looks like your plot is doing the right thing. Could you expand on what is the problem?

Comment: I deleted the first line of code that got you confused. My concern is that one facet is showing only one series and one facet is showing two series. It should be both the facets should display both the series. One on solid and one on dashed. Only one facet is doing that.

Comment: If  you look at `table(watersurf$group1, watersurf$coupleid)` you will see that one facet have one kind of data. I could get thing wrong, but have a look at the table, `table(watersurf$group1, watersurf$coupleid)`.

Comment: I used `ggplot(data=watersurf,aes(x=time,y=data,group=id))+geom_line(aes(linetype=group1, colour = group1), size = 0.2)+facet_wrap(~coupleid)` to get a better look at the wo series, and to me it still looks like both facets is showing showing one series. 1 is showing the modeled and 2 is showing the observed.

Comment: You might be right. But if I change the code little bit like this then I can see both the series but legend seems to be messed up.  ggplot(data=watersurf,aes(x=time,y=data,group=id))+geom_line(aes(linetype=group1,colour=id),size=0.2)+facet_wrap(~coupleid) It seems like the code line watersurf$coupleid has minor problem. I created this code based on http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/growth.htm.

Comment: @ Eric Fail Thank you so much. Such an elegant code without any confusion. My code was complicated. I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @ Eric Fall, what do I need to do to create scatter plot between blue modeled vs blue observed and red modeled vs red observed from this data set. Do I need to do some modification ?

Comment: @Jdbaba, try taking a look at [these examples](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_point.html) from the ggplot2 0.9.3 manual.